# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException and non blocking sockets

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nio, networkonmainthread

I using Java nio sockets in non blocking mode, but when i call write i still get NetworkOnMainThreadException.

```
java.nio.channels.SocketChannel fd = Network.createTcpSocket();
java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open();
java.net.Socket socket = fd.socket();
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
fd.configureBlocking(false);

//.. conect the socket

int ret = fd.write(data);
if(ret == 0)
{
  // It will block.
}
```

I will expect this to work as the socket will not block and just return 0 in case the call need to block. But i still receive the NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
12-07 18:50:25.704: W/dalvikvm(14931): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c501f8)
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:168)
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:477)
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931):    at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.writeImpl(SocketChannelImpl.java:369)
12-07 18:50:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(14931):    at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:327
```

Comment: how can you expect to write data in a non-blocking fashion and still get the number of bytes written on the next line?

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, a write operation will return only after writing all of the r requested bytes. Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or possibly none at all. A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for example, cannot write any more bytes than are free in the socket's output buffer.

Comment: when would it write the rest, then?

Comment: you must call it later, when the selector told you that the SocketOperation.Write has end

Comment: but on which thread does it occur ? apparently it is still running on the ui

Comment: nio socket is non blocking mode doesn't block that is a fact, i was just surprised that Android disallow to use non blocking call in the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException :](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for making network related task from Ui Thread

or you are using **API LEVEL 9** then  just set [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) for Current Activity in `onCreate()` method before making network request :

```
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
   .detectNetwork() // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
   .penaltyDialog()  //show a dialog
   //.permitNetwork() //permit Network access 
   .build());
```

Comment: yes i read that before, but as all this was to avoid non blocking the UI thread, i was surprised that you canont do async io

Answer (score 2):

Android's justification for throwing a NetworkOnMainThreadException
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException

is detailed in the document "Designing for Responsiveness"
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr

But Android makes the mistake of assuming all network IO can cause UI unresponsiveness.

Java non-blocking NIO (and Java NIO.2) channel methods by definition do not block and thus cannot cause an unresponsive UI.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel#bm

> A selectable channel is either in blocking mode or in non-blocking mode. In blocking mode, every I/O operation invoked upon the channel will block until it completes. In non-blocking mode an I/O operation will never block ...

It is a shame Android does not recognize this and thus causes developers to add an unnecessary background layer of abstraction (AsyncTask be the most clumsy) between the UI and Java non-blocking NIO network operations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behavior. I guess there's a check inside of Socket class, no matter is it blocking and non-blocking. If thread is UI - throw NetworkOnMainThreadException